# Showing one of the DIV elements, depending on user input value

Tags: javascript, css

I'm struggling...

I have an `<input>` field. Depending on the input, one of the various `<div>` elements should be shown. In this example it's just a text (e.g. "Dein Plan enthält weniger als 1500 kcal!"), later the div elements will be whole blocks with pictures, buttons, etc.

I have found some ideas with jQuery but as I've never worked with it, I don't understand it. So i tried if with the if-function and changing the style:none to block.

What am I doing wrong? The div doens't want to appear... I'm a beginner with Javascript, so if you have a tip, please explain it for an absolute rookie :)

Thank you guys!

HTML

```
<body style="background-color:#000000">

<form>
    <p>
        <label for=bedarf> Mein Bedarf </label>
        <input type="bedarf" name="bedarf" id="bedarf" placeholder="2345">
        <button class="button1" type="button" id="berechnen" onclick="planholen()" > Plan anzeigen </button><br><br><br>
</form>

<div class="anzeige" id="erster" ><p>Dein Plan enthält weniger als 1500 kcal!</p></div>
<div class="anzeige" id="zweiter" ><p>Dein Plan enthält weniger als 1700 kcal!</p></div>
<div class="anzeige" id="dritter" ><p>Dein Plan enthält weniger als 1900 kcal!</p></div>
<div class="anzeige" id="vierter" ><p>Dein Plan enthält weniger als 2100 kcal!</p></div>
<div class="anzeige" id="funfter" ><p>Dein Plan enthält weniger als 2300 kcal!</p></div>
<div class="anzeige" id="sechster" ><p>Dein Plan enthält weniger als 2500 kcal!</p></div>
<div class="anzeige" id="siebter" ><p>Dein Plan enthält weniger als 2700 kcal!</p></div>
<div class="anzeige" id="achter" ><p>Dein Plan enthält weniger als 2900 kcal!</p></div>
<div class="anzeige" id="neunter" ><p>Dein Plan enthält weniger als 3100 kcal!</p></div>
<div class="anzeige" id="zehnter" ><p>Dein Plan enthält weniger als 3300 kcal!</p></div>
<div class="anzeige" id="elfter" ><p>Dein Plan enthält weniger als 3500 kcal!</p></div>
<div class="anzeige" id="zwölfter" ><p>Dein Plan enthält weniger als 3700 kcal!</p></div>
<div class="anzeige" id="dreizehnter" ><p>Dein Plan enthält weniger als 3900 kcal!</p></div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
<style>

label {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
}

input {
    width: 120px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px
}


.button1 {
    width:130px;
    height:25px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 4px;
}

button {
  background-color: #ddca07; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  height:30px; 
  width:50px; 
  padding: 2px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  background-color: black; 
  color: white; 
  border: 1px solid #ddca07;
  width:140px;
  height:25px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style:bold;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #ddca07;
  color: black;
}

.anzeige {
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#ffffff;
    display:none;
    }

</style>
```

JS

```
<script>

function planholen() {
    var a = document.getElementById("erster");
    var b = document.getElementById("zweiter");
    var c = document.getElementById("dritter");
    var d = document.getElementById("vierter");
    var e = document.getElementById("funfter");
    var f = document.getElementById("sechster");
    var g = document.getElementById("siebter");
    var h = document.getElementById("achter");
    var i = document.getElementById("neunter");
    var j = document.getElementById("zehnter");
    var k = document.getElementById("elfter");
    var l = document.getElementById("zwölfter");
    var m = document.getElementById("dreizehnter");

    var val = parseInt(document.getElementById("bedarf");

    if (val < 1500) { a.style.display = "block"; } else
    if (val < 1700) { b.style.display = "block"; } else
    if (val < 1900) { c.style.display = "block"; } else
    if (val < 2100) { d.style.display = "block"; } else
    if (val < 2300) { e.style.display = "block"; } else
    if (val < 2500) { f.style.display = "block"; } else
    if (val < 2700) { g.style.display = "block"; } else
    if (val < 2900) { h.style.display = "block"; } else
    if (val < 3100) { i.style.display = "block"; } else
    if (val < 3300) { j.style.display = "block"; } else
    if (val < 3500) { k.style.display = "block"; } else
    if (val < 3700) { l.style.display = "block"; } else
    if (val < 3900) { m.style.display = "block"; } 


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added my version that works below. Have a look and see if you can make sense of it all. Don't get discouraged, I know it can feel overwhelming at first but it'll soon be fun again :)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Your diet-Plan</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  form {
   margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  label {
   width: 100px;
   display: inline-block;
   font-family: Arial;
   color: #fff;
  }

  input {
   width: 120px;
   height: 25px;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 14px;
  }

  .button1 {
   width: 130px;
   height: 25px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 250px;
   top: 4px;
  }

  button {
   background-color: #ddca07; /* Green */
   border: none;
   color: white;
   height: 30px;
   width: 50px;
   padding: 2px 10px;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 20px;
   margin: 4px 2px;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
   transition-duration: 0.4s;
   cursor: pointer;
  }

  button {
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
   border: 1px solid #ddca07;
   width: 140px;
   height: 25px;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-style: bold;
  }

  button:hover {
   background-color: #ddca07;
   color: black;
  }

  .anzeige {
   font-family: Arial;
   color: #fff;
  }

  .anzeige:empty {
   display: none;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#000000">
 <form id="diat">
  <label for=bedarf>Mein Bedarf</label>
  <input type="text" name="bedarf" id="bedarf" placeholder="2345">
  <button class="button1" type="submit">Plan anzeigen</button>
 </form>
 <div class="anzeige" id="anzeige"></div>

 <script>
  function planholen( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var bedarf = parseInt( document.getElementById('bedarf').value ) || 0;
   var bedarfGerundet = Math.ceil( bedarf / 100 ) * 100;
   var anzeige = document.getElementById('anzeige');
   if( bedarf > 0 ) {
    anzeige.innerHTML = 'Dein Plan enthält weniger als ' + bedarfGerundet + ' kcal!';
   }
   else {
    anzeige.innerHTML = '';
   }
  }

  document.getElementById('diat').addEventListener('submit', planholen);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I kept to your specs as much as I could but did added a bunch of things here and there.

1. I added `.anzeige:empty { display: none; }` in your css as that keeps you from having to handle that logic. Just empty the div now and it will be hidden.
2. I kept the original input data as `bedarf` to make sure we may access this later again
3. I assumed you want to empty the div when nothing was inserted
4. I insert the text now via js rather than having it in the DOM already (much smaller)
5. instead of executing my function on click I now execute it on submit which means when someone hits the `return` key it still works (more a11y)
6. I kept as much German in there as I could with my limited German skills :)

Your code had some issues:

1. `var val = parseInt(document.getElementById("bedarf");` is missing a closing bracket
2. If someone would have entered something and hit your button and than changed their mind and entered a new button and hit the button again they would have gotten several messages which I assume is not the intent
3. The aforementioned `submit on return` issue
4. `if (val < 1500) { a.style.display = "block"; } else` is very hard to read for my anyway... try using a new line for the `else if` statement

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what I wanted to do! In the code snippet it's working perfectly :) I will go trough to understand it in total and adapt the div elements to the final boxes. Thanks again!!

Comment: One question, I have seen that you've made it with the text string and var `anzeige.innerHTML = 'Dein Plan enthält weniger als ' + bedarfGerundet + ' kcal!';` My end aim is to have different `<div>` blocks which should be showed depending on the value. Is that possible?

Comment: That's possible but like I said above it would mean you have to implement the hiding of all divs and showing only one plus it's unnecessarily a lot of code. I assume there is a different use-case here?

Answer (score 0):

I have attached demo version's. You may find it useful.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div style="border:solid 1px #ddd; padding:10px; display:block;">
          <div>
              <label>Number:</label>
              <div><input id="number" name="value" /></div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <p>
          <input type="button" value="Click Here" id="bt" onclick="planholen(this)">
      </p>
      <div class="anzeige" id="erster" style="display:block;">
        <p>Dein Plan enthält weniger als 1500 kcal!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="anzeige" id="zweiter" style="display:block;">
        <p>Dein Plan enthält weniger als 1700 kcal!</p>
      </div>
  </body>
  <script>
      function planholen(ele) {
          if(document.getElementById('number').value < 1500){
            document.getElementById('erster').style.display = 'none';
          }
          if(document.getElementById('number').value < 1700){
            document.getElementById('zweiter').style.display = 'none';
          }
      }
  </script>
</html>
```